# Mongoose - Increment Field On Subdoc if exists, else create new

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## What I am trying to do.

I have a `userSchema` that contains a list of `operationCountSchema`objects. What I am trying to do, is to create a static method that updates the `count` field on one of these operation count subdocuments if it exists (identified by a `month_id`) field. If an `operationCountSchema` document does not exist for the current month, it should create a new document. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour in mongoose? I have tried using upsert to no avail. How would one do this? Thanks.

## CODE

```
var operationCountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    month_id: String,
    count: { type: Number, default: 0 }
}, {_id : false});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username : { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: String,
    operation_counts: [operationCountSchema]
});

userSchema.statics.incrementOperationCount = function(userID, callback) {
    var currDate = new Date();
    var dateIdentifier = currDate.getFullYear() + "-" + currDate.getMonth();
    //NEED TO INCREMENT OPERATION COUNT IF ONE FOR MONTH EXISTS, 
    //ELSE IF IT DOES NOT EXIST, CREATE A NEW ONE.
}
```

Also, any suggestions on alternative ways in which this functionality can be achieved are welcome.

Comment: Pass the values through static method and check whether the sub-document exist(using `this` keyword). If exist modify and call callback. Else create sub-document using `this.sub-docment = <your-values>` and call the callback. Once the callback is called use mongoose document  `save()` method to save modified document.

Comment: What does `month_id` needs to match to to increment the count?

Comment: @Chinni month_id needs to match dateIdentifier.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want [`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) with `upsert : true`:

```
operationCountSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
  month_id : dateIdentifier,
}, { 
  $inc : { count : 1 }
}, {
  upsert : true
}, callback);
```

(untested)

Comment: I think that you have misunderstood my code/question. month_id is not unique. The operation count schema's need to be queried based on the the user that it is a subdocument of.

Comment: @AnthonyDito ah, I thought you were using a separate collection, but you're using subdocs. In which case, I don't think you can get it working in a single step, which means that any updates will be prone to race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two steps, here is a example in `mongo shell`:

```
mongos> db.collection.findOne()    
{
    "username" : "mark",
    "email" : "admin@example.com",
    "password" : "balalalala",
    "operation_counts" : [
        {
            "month_id" : "2016-05",
            "count" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

First, make sure the subdoc exists, if not just create one use `$addToSet`.

```
mongos> db.collection.update({username:"mark", "operation_counts.month_id": {$ne:"2016-05"}}, {$addToSet: {"operation_counts":{month_id: "2016-05", count:0}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
// only update when the subdoc of specified month not exists
mongos> db.collection.update({username:"mark", "operation_counts.month_id": {$ne:"2016-06"}}, {$addToSet: {"operation_counts":{month_id: "2016-06", count:0}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

mongos> db.collection.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575636c21e9b27fe715df654"),
    "username" : "mark",
    "email" : "admin@example.com",
    "password" : "balalalala",
    "operation_counts" : [
        {
            "month_id" : "2016-05",
            "count" : 6
        },
        {
            "month_id" : "2016-06",
            "count" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, increment the `count` field.

```
mongos> db.collection.update({username:"mark", "operation_counts.month_id": "2016-06"}, {$inc:{ "operation_counts.$.count":1 }})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

mongos> db.collection.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575636c21e9b27fe715df654"),
    "username" : "mark",
    "email" : "admin@example.com",
    "password" : "balalalala",
    "operation_counts" : [
        {
            "month_id" : "2016-05",
            "count" : 6
        },
        {
            "month_id" : "2016-06",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing something similar. This does appear to be the best solution. As it stands now. I will award you the bounty.

Comment: Eh, I'm using `$ne` operator to match, so you should ensure other condition can use index, and `operation_counts` array won't get too large.

Answer (score 1):

So you can have a `mongoose.find()` or `mongoose.findOne()` and check if the sub-document exists. If it doesn't we can create the a new object and if it does, we can increment and save.

Here I'm using `mongoose.findOne()`. Refer to the docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

```
userSchema.statics.incrementOperationCount = function(userID, callback) {
var currDate = new Date();
var dateIdentifier = currDate.getFullYear() + "-" + currDate.getMonth();
    //NEED TO INCREMENT OPERATION COUNT IF ONE FOR MONTH EXISTS, 
    //ELSE IF IT DOES NOT EXIST, CREATE A NEW ONE.
    operationCountSchema.findOne({'month_id': dateIdentifier}, function(err, subDoc) {
        // If there is an error in finding the document, catch them
        if(err) {
            // Handle errors
            return err;
        }
        // If you find a document, increment the `count` and save
        if(subDoc) {
            subDoc.count += 1;
            subDoc.save(function(err2) {
                if(err2) {
                    // Handle errors
                    return err2;
                } else {
                    return "Success";
                }
            });
        } 
        // If no document is found, create a new one
        else {
            // Populate the values to create the object
            var data = {
                "month_id": dateIdentifier,
                "count": 0
            };
            operationCountSchema.create(data, function(err3, subDoc) {
                if(err3) {
                    // Handle errors
                    return err3;
                }
                // Else return success
                return "Success";
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Let me know if I got your question worng or didn't address something.

Comment: You didn't address concurrency issues or race conditions. In between the `findOne` and `save` or `create`, another possible database writer could have already updated/created the count.

Comment: So multiple people have permissions to update the same document record simultaneously?

Comment: It's perfectly possible with MongoDB that a document gets updated by another writer in the time _between_ `findOne` and `save/create`, because MongoDB doesn't have transactions.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. I just came across this in the official docs https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/metadata-and-asset-management/#create-and-edit-content-nodes. I haven't implemented it or used it before. Please check that and let me also know what are the conclusions.

Comment: I'm familiar with that method, but I wonder if it'll work in this particular case (especially because you also have to deal with the fact that a record may not even exist yet). The `findOneAndUpdate` operation that I suggest in my answer uses an _atomic_ operation ([`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)) to deal with concurrency issues.

Comment: I searched a lot but couldn't find how to programmatically lock the db when you are creating a document object in mongodb. So my idea is to do it in the application layer by checking/storing a value in `.txt` file. Depending on the value, we can decide to create or delay the creation. But this works well if `month_id` will be unique in your application. If not, we have to do a work around by repeating the whole process after a delay (including `findOne()` function). I hope I'm clear with my explanation. Let me know your views.

Comment: You should read the documentation I linked to (about `findAndModify`), that will perform atomic updates _or_ create a new document if necessary (using `upsert`), without explicit locking. Using a `.txt` file is also prone to concurrency issues (what if you have more than one server running?).

Comment: Great! Then I think yours should be the accepted answer.